# Extracting data from pixels of a contour plot figure in Python or MATLAB

Tags: python, matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure, contour

I have a contour plot like this:

[image: a sample contour plot]

Now, **if I do not have the data to generate the contour plot and all I have is the image,** how can I extract the values for each and every pixel from the image and store it in an array?

Any suggestions or examples in MATLAB/Python would be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

If you know the pixle values, using *find*, you can find the locations you want.

```
I = imread('y5dZ1.png');
I1 = rgb2gray(I) ;
%%
pix = [48 : 10 : 200] ;
[y,x] = find(I1==200) ;

imshow(I)
hold on
plot(x,y,'.r')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small Matlab script that will do the job (using some GUI, read the guidlines at the tiltle of the figure):

```
%// Import the data:
imdata = importdata('your_picture_file');
Gray = rgb2gray(imdata.cdata);
colorLim = [-1 1]; %// this should be set manually
%// Get the area of the data:
f = figure('Position',get(0,'ScreenSize'));
imshow(imdata.cdata,'Parent',axes('Parent',f),'InitialMagnification','fit');
%// Get the area of the data:
title('Click with the cross on the most top left area of the *data*')
da_tp_lft = round(getPosition(impoint));
title('Click with the cross on the most bottom right area of the *data*') 
da_btm_rgt = round(getPosition(impoint));
dat_area = double(Gray(da_tp_lft(2):da_btm_rgt(2),da_tp_lft(1):da_btm_rgt(1)));
%// Get the area of the colorbar:
title('Click with the cross within the upper most color of the *colorbar*')
ca_tp_lft = round(getPosition(impoint));
title('Click with the cross within the bottom most color of the *colorbar*')
ca_btm_rgt = round(getPosition(impoint));
cmap_area = double(Gray(ca_tp_lft(2):ca_btm_rgt(2),ca_tp_lft(1):ca_btm_rgt(1)));
close(f)
%// Convert the colormap to data:
data = dat_area./max(cmap_area(:)).*range(colorLim)-abs(min(colorLim));
```

Now, `data` is what you look for.

Here is an illustration of the output using the figure in the question:

[image]

The code for the illustration:

```
figure('Position',[100 200 1200 400]);
subplot 121
imshow(imdata.cdata)
hold on
plot(da_tp_lft(1),da_tp_lft(2),'m+','MarkerSize',7,'LineWidth',2)
plot(da_btm_rgt(1),da_btm_rgt(2),'m+','MarkerSize',7,'LineWidth',2)
plot(ca_tp_lft(1),ca_tp_lft(2),'r+','MarkerSize',7,'LineWidth',2)
plot(ca_btm_rgt(1),ca_btm_rgt(2),'r+','MarkerSize',7,'LineWidth',2)
hold off
title('The original image')

subplot 122
surf(data)
shading interp
view(50,40)
colorbar
caxis([-1 1])
title('Illusration of the data')
axis tight
```

Comment: @arun please let me know if this answer helps you, or you look for something different.